# How to parse placeholders from text without throwing away your sword so you can fight off the marauders with a lampshade

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I needed to parse placeholders out of text like `abc $$FOO$$ cba`. I hacked to together something with Scala's parser combinators, but I'm not really happy with the solution.

In particular, I resorted to a zero-width matcher in the regular expression `(?=(\$\$|\z))` to stop parsing the text and start parsing the placeholders. This sounds perilously close to the shenanigans discussed and colorfully dismissed on the [scala mailing list](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/1943#comment-6780) (which inspired the title of this question.)

So, the challenge: fix my parser to work without this hack. I'd like to see a clear progression from the problem to your solution, so I can replace my strategy of randomly assembling combinators until tests pass.

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

object PlaceholderParser extends RegexParsers {
  sealed abstract class Element
  case class Text(text: String) extends Element
  case class Placeholder(key: String) extends Element

  override def skipWhitespace = false

  def parseElements(text: String): List[Element] = parseAll(elements, text) match {
    case Success(es, _) => es
    case NoSuccess(msg, _) => error("Could not parse: [%s]. Error: %s".format(text, msg))
  }

  def parseElementsOpt(text: String): ParseResult[List[Element]] = parseAll(elements, text)

  lazy val elements: Parser[List[Element]] = rep(element)
  lazy val element: Parser[Element] = placeholder ||| text
  lazy val text: Parser[Text] = """(?ims).+?(?=(\$\$|\z))""".r ^^ Text.apply
  lazy val placeholder: Parser[Placeholder] = delimiter ~> """[\w. ]+""".r <~ delimiter ^^ Placeholder.apply
  lazy val delimiter: Parser[String] = literal("$$")
}


import org.junit.{Assert, Test}

class PlaceholderParserTest {
  @Test
  def parse1 = check("a quick brown $$FOX$$ jumped over the lazy $$DOG$$")(Text("a quick brown "), Placeholder("FOX"), Text(" jumped over the lazy "), Placeholder("DOG"))

  @Test
  def parse2 = check("a quick brown $$FOX$$!")(Text("a quick brown "), Placeholder("FOX"), Text("!"))

  @Test
  def parse3 = check("a quick brown $$FOX$$!\n!")(Text("a quick brown "), Placeholder("FOX"), Text("!\n!"))

  @Test
  def parse4 = check("a quick brown $$F.O X$$")(Text("a quick brown "), Placeholder("F.O X"))

  def check(text: String)(expected: Element*) = Assert.assertEquals(expected.toList, parseElements(text))
}
```

Comment: It might be simpler to run a regexp-based lexer first, splitting the input into tokens that are either "$$" or "a string not containing $$". For that matter, since your delimiters aren't in matching nestable pairs, isn't this just a regular language anyway? What you're doing looks more like "covering a lamp" than "fighting marauders" to me.

Comment: Sounds like a step in the right direction. How should I choose how to divide the work between the lexer and the scanner?

Comment: Incidentally, if you're replying to a comment, prefixing it with @ their username will make it show up in their "new replies". Otherwise only the author of the question/answer will be notified. I would have responded to your query if I'd seen it. :(

Comment: To belatedly reply, it's hard to say in this case because the grammar is so simple. I'd possibly do something like use a lexer to produce a stream of "delimiter" and "character" tokens. On the other hand, I could also see ditching lexing and regexes entirely and adding explicit backtracking into a per-character parser itself to handle $ vs. $$. I'd write up examples, but I don't know Scala and Haskell + Parsec might not be similar enough to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I found another approach. There's no regex hack anymore, but the code is a little bit longer. It parses the whole string to a list of single characters or `Placeholder` objects. The `compact` function then compacts the list (i.e. it converts consecutive strings to `Text` objects and does not touch the `Placeholder` objects):

```
object PlaceholderParser extends RegexParsers {
  sealed abstract class Element
  case class Text(text: String) extends Element
  case class Placeholder(key: String) extends Element

  override def skipWhitespace = false

  def parseElements(text: String): List[Element] = parseAll(elements, text) match {
    case Success(es, _) => es
    case NoSuccess(msg, _) => error("Could not parse: [%s]. Error: %s".format(text, msg))
  }

  def parseElementsOpt(text: String): ParseResult[List[Element]] = parseAll(elements, text)

  def compact(l: List[Any]): List[Element] = {
    val builder = new StringBuilder()
    val r = l.foldLeft(List.empty[Element])((l, e) => e match {
      case s: String =>
        builder.append(s)
        l
      case p: Placeholder =>
        val t = if (builder.size > 0) {
          val k = l ++ List(Text(builder.toString))
          builder.clear
          k
        } else {
          l
        }
        t ++ List(p)
    })
    if (builder.size > 0) r ++ List(Text(builder.toString)) else r
  }

  lazy val elements: Parser[List[Element]] = (placeholder ||| text).+ ^^ compact
  lazy val text: Parser[String] = """(?ims).""".r
  lazy val placeholder: Parser[Placeholder] = delimiter ~> """[\w. ]+""".r <~ delimiter ^^ Placeholder.apply
  lazy val delimiter: Parser[String] = literal("$$")
}
```

It's not a perfect solution, but maybe something you can start with.